# Why is my reverse of an array code not working as it should

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

Hey so below is the code that i came up with can some explain me what is wrong its reverse of an array

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[4] = {1,4,3,2};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n = size - 1;
    cout << size << endl;
    cout << n << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[n - i];
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, "why/how is it 'not working'"?

Comment: hey @user2864740 the output that i am getting for this code is 2332 for first two elements are getting printed correctly and the next two are repeating!
And i did write it down first
arr[0] = arr[3] ;
arr[1] = arr[2] ;
arr[2] = arr[1] ;
arr[3] = arr[0] .

Comment: ok got  it so basically if i do this since it is replacing the initial two values with the reverse values the initial two values are deleted hence the issue, thanks paper and pen worked @user2864740

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question.  But effectively, instead of swapping the values from opposite ends of the array, you're overwriting the values at the beginning with those at the end, and once you reached the mid point, you start to copy those back into the second half.

As you wrote:
`arr[0] = arr[3];`
but later
`arr[3] = arr[0];`
which is just a long winded way of reversing the second half of the array twice.